# Codeigniter Ajax not returning any error message if the data is not matched in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with AJAX in CodeIgniter.

Here is my code. This is working when my SQL query returns a result. If the query is empty, AJAX doesn't return anything.

My Model:

```
function view_filter_by_cat($id){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_FILTER_OPTION." WHERE FID=?";
$query=$this->db->query($sql,$id);
if($query->num_rows()){
    foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        $result[] = $row;
    }           
    $query->free_result();
    return $result;         
}
```

AJAX Controller:

```
public function find_filters_options(){
    if($this->input->post('FID')){
        $fid = $this->input->post('FID');
        $filterList= $this->filter_option_model->view_filter_by_cat($fid);          
        if($this->filter_option_model->view_filter_by_cat($fid)){               
            echo (json_encode($filterList));
        }else{              
            echo '0';
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax calling:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/products/find_filters_options'); ?>',
    data: {
        <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?> : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
        FID: fid
    },
    success: function(data1){
        alert(data1);
    }
});
```

My question is when the query doesn't return any value, I am unable to access the success message. I want to get the value '0', when the return is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change you controller to like:

```
public function find_filters_options(){
  $result = array();
    if($this->input->post('FID')){
        $fid = $this->input->post('FID');
        $filterList= $this->filter_option_model->view_filter_by_cat($fid);          
        if($this->filter_option_model->view_filter_by_cat($fid)){               
            $result["got_data"] = "yes";
            $result["data"] = $filterList;            
        }else{              
            $result["got_data"] = "no";
        }
    }
    else {
      $result["got_data"] = "no";
    }
    echo (json_encode($result));
}
```

And your jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/products/find_filters_options'); ?>',
  data : {<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?> : '<?php echo 
$this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', FID : fid },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data1) {
    if(data1.got_data == "yes") {
        var data = data1.data; //get data from server here
    } 
    else {
       //dont have any data
       //show some appropriate message
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but this is also not working :( i think something wrong with the model, because i didn't receive any data from the else

Comment: i cant able to trace the problem via browser console too

Comment: hey r u there? i got one issue, i can't able to access the data.
var data = data1.data; i am getting undefined error, i am 100% sure controller has the data variable and i can see the data variable when i alert the whole alert(data1)

Comment: @SoundharRaj try checking console.log(data1); to see what you get, and also try console.log(data1["data"]);